# VBA　高速化について

Tags: vba, excel

VBAでデータの整形、整理を行っていますが、
とにかく処理が遅くて困っております。

調べたところ、セルに直接書き込む処理を減らすため
配列を使い、セルに直接書き込む回数を減らすことで
速度の改善が可能とのことが分かりました。

そこで、一旦、テキストファイルを読み込んで表示されたセル範囲を
regionArr = Range("A1").CurrentRegionとし、配列として格納した
のですが、ここから、それぞれの列に対して、どのように記載をして
いけばよいのか分かりません。

処理イメージとしては、画像の様になります。
（自分が書いた、遅い、重いマクロでは実現できています）

```
Sub sample()
    Dim txtPath As String
    Dim regionArr As Variant
     
'テキスト読み込み処理
    txtPath = "C:\Work\sample.log"

    'Textファイル読み込み
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=txtPath, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
    
    'Textを読み込んだ領域を配列として格納
    regionArr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    

'読み込んだテキストに対する処理
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    lastRow = UBound(regionArr)

'A列に対しての処理
'B列に対しての処理
'C列に対しての処理など

end sub
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「VBAでデータの整形、整理を行っていますが、とにかく処理が遅くて困っております。」とのことですが、データが多いことが遅い原因でしょうか？VBAで処理する以外に計算式等で計算処理はしていないということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: そもそもVBAでなくPowerQueryで処理することをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regionArr には範囲のセルの内容が２次元配列として入ります。
内容を確認してみてください。

```
Dim nRow As Long
Dim nColumn As Long
For nRow = LBound(regionArr, 1) To UBound(regionArr, 1)
    For nColumn = LBound(regionArr, 2) To UBound(regionArr, 2)
        Debug.Print nRow, nColumn, regionArr(nRow, nColumn)
    Next
Next
```

その後はデータを加工して２次元配列を作り、範囲指定をして代入します。

```
targetSheet.Range("A2:C13").Value = 加工後の２次元配列
```

Comment: なかなか理解が難しいため、セル範囲を配列化した後の処理については、別に質問させていただきます。